# Angularjs file upload with spring mvc 3.0 as backend not working - Getting 404 error

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am new to Spring MVC and Angularjs , I am trying to do a file upload using Angularjs and spring MVC here is my html file:

When I start the tomcat server and try to run the application, I am getting 404 error ,resource is not available.Below is the url i use:

http://localhost:9090/Test/api/userfile/fileUploadForm

FileUpload.html

> 

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>UserConfig FileUpload</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // load angularjs specific version
    var angularVersion = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (angularVersion.indexOf('/') == 0) angularVersion =  
    angularVersion.substring(1);
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/' +
        (angularVersion || '1.2.24') + '/angular.js"><\/script>');
 </script>

<script  type="text/javascript" src="siteConfig.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller = "SiteFileUploadCtrl">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

siteConfig.js

> var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function(){
                scope.$apply(function(){
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            withCredentials : false,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
            console.log("success 1");
        })
        .error(function(){
            console.log("error");
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('SiteFileUploadCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload',  
 function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        alert("hi");
        console.log("hello");
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is');
        console.dir(file);
        var uploadUrl = '/Test/login/api/userfile/upload';
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

Below is my Spring Controller code:

UploadController.java

> 

```
package com.net.controller;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/userfile/")
public class UploadController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/fileUploadForm")
    public ModelAndView getUploadForm() {

        return new ModelAndView("FileUpload");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String upload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file ) throws IOException {
        String fileName = null;
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                File newFile = new File("C:\\test\\" + fileName);
                BufferedOutputStream buffStream = 
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(newFile));
                buffStream.write(bytes);
                buffStream.close();
                return "You have successfully uploaded " + fileName;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + fileName + ": " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "Unable to upload. File is empty.";
        }
    }
}
```

Spring-context.xml full code:

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.net.controller" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

</beans>
```

Below is my web.xml full code:

> 

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <display-name>test</display-name>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The js files are placed under WEB-INF/scripts and the source html pages(FileUpload.html) are placed under WebContent/pages.

the spring-context.xml and web.xml are placed under the WEB-INF folder .The controller class is under com.net.controller

Now when 
I know I am doing some configuration and mapping wrong.I couldnt get that one.

Can anyone please point out the mapping mistake. Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid api address like you submit upload file on /upload i.e if you site is running on `localhost:8080` and upload url is `localhost:8080/upload`.but you have create backend url is `@RequestMapping("api/userfile/")` on controller and `@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)` on method which mean your backend url is

api/userfile/upload

that why you getting 404 for that.You can change your angular url from **/upload** to **/api/userfile/upload**.it will be work for you.

Comment: Charnjeet: Thanks for your response, But I changed the angularurl to /api/userfile/upload and i hit the application url as below:localhost:9090/Test/api/userfile/fileUploadForm, I am still getting the 404 error. Will it be due to some mapping error in web.xml or so?

Comment: Also , When I hit the application url like localhost:9090/Test/api/userfile/upload, then it says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) error

Comment: are you runing project on GRUNT or Server (Tomcat)?

Comment: I am running the project in Tomcat

Comment: http 404 error is now solved and the page is displaying when i hit the url : http://localhost:9090/Test/login/api/userfile/fileUploadForm. When I click the upload button in the form , the file is successfully getting uploaded to the above location. But , in the upload method in spring I am returning a string like "file is successfully uploaded", this string is not getting displayed in the page. Any idea?

Comment: Even I change the return type to ModelAndView and tried to return a new ModelAndView, that is also not displaying in the page ,Also I do not see any errors in the console log, Can anyone please suggest me how to solve this?

Comment: you can change your return type to json and send result as bean.